# Unfortunately, App has Stopped Android Deevelopment Error

Tags: android, eclipse, crash

when I try to open up a new activity called areacircle, it shows the error: "Unfortunately, Essentials has Stopped".  I am 100% sure that the problem does not consist in the Manifest file. I think there might be some problem in my code.

**EDIT: I UPDATED acircle CODE AND LogCat, THE PROGRAM STILL CRASHES**

areacircle xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="@string/acirclefirstnumbtn"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/radiusedittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/radius"
    android:textSize="30sp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="findarea"
    android:text="@string/findarea"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/area"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/areatextview"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

areacircle code:

```
package com.turnapps.essentials;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class areacircle extends Activity {

    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    private static double radius;
    Button button1;
    EditText radiusedittext;
    TextView answer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.areacircle);
         textView1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         textView2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         radiusedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.radiusedittext);
         answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);

    }
     double pi = 3.14;
     double radiusedittext1 = radius;
     double areatextview;

    public void findarea(View sender){


        areatextview = radiusedittext1 * radiusedittext1 * pi;
        answer.getText().equals(areatextview);
    }
    }
```

Here is the code of findmy (the activity where I am launching areacircle from):

```
public class findmy extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.findmy);
    Button d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.circleareabtn);
    d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent acircleIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                    areacircle.class);
            startActivity(acircleIntent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Here is the LogCat content:

```
08-27 14:14:57.731: E/Trace(2726): error opening trace file: No such file or directory  (2)
08-27 14:14:58.101: D/gralloc_goldfish(2726): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-27 14:34:43.373: E/Trace(2838): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-27 14:34:45.123: D/gralloc_goldfish(2838): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-27 14:34:55.630: D/dalvikvm(2838): GC_CONCURRENT freed 166K, 11% free 2610K/2908K, paused 72ms+33ms, total 261ms
08-27 14:35:02.010: D/AndroidRuntime(2838): Shutting down VM
08-27 14:35:02.030: W/dalvikvm(2838): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.turnapps.essentials/com.turnapps.essentials.areacircle}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at com.turnapps.essentials.areacircle.onCreate(areacircle.java:21)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     ... 11 more
08-27 14:36:21.561: E/Trace(2872): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-27 14:36:21.881: D/AndroidRuntime(2872): Shutting down VM
08-27 14:36:21.881: W/dalvikvm(2872): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:379)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:322)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
08-27 14:36:21.901: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     ... 11 more
08-27 14:36:32.331: E/Trace(2903): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-27 14:36:34.631: D/gralloc_goldfish(2903): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-27 14:36:37.820: D/dalvikvm(2903): GC_CONCURRENT freed 170K, 11% free 2604K/2904K,  paused 75ms+94ms, total 309ms
08-27 14:36:45.061: D/AndroidRuntime(2903): Shutting down VM
08-27 14:36:45.071: W/dalvikvm(2903): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.turnapps.essentials/com.turnapps.essentials.areacircle}:  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to  android.widget.EditText
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at com.turnapps.essentials.areacircle.onCreate(areacircle.java:21)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-27 14:36:45.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: check all id that have pace each id in good pace and matched with xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize view's in `onCreate` after `setContentView`. You need to set the content to the activity first and then initialize views. Your initialization fails leading to `NullPointerException`.

```
TextView textView1;
TextView textView2;
private static double radius;
Button button1;
EditText radiusedittext;
TextView answer;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.areacircle);
     textView1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     textView2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     radiusedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.radiusedittext);
     answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
}
```

Edit

You have this

```
   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/answer"
```

And this

```
  TextView answer;
```

Bu you do

```
   answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer); // wrong casting to edittext
```

So replace above statement by the below

```
   answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
```

Comment: I have changed the areacircle code, and updated it in my initial post, as well as the LogCat. The program still crashes unfortunately. Can you see how you can help me with the updated information? Thanks!

Comment: @shariqbal shows us your xml par. it seems you have a textview in xml but while initializing you are casting it to editext.

Comment: I have added the xml to the initial post!

Comment: @shariqbal this a very simple error you must be able to debug besides logcat has all the details you need. you are casting textview to edittext which is wrong

Comment: How exactly do I debug? And can you tell me how you determined this error? I am still new to Android

Comment: Did you actually read logcat? **Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
08-27 14:35:02.100: E/AndroidRuntime(2838):     at com.turnapps.essentials.areacircle.onCreate(areacircle.java:21)** even gives you line number line 21 areacircle.java.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

> com.turnapps.essentials.areacircle.(areacircle.java:11)

Seems to be the culprit.

**Edit**

On line 21 of your class, you assign EditText objects to what you declared to be TextView variables. These are two different types of views, what are you trying to do? Have EditTexts or TextViews?

Also, just as a guideline, it is common practice to have class names starting with capital letters: areacircle would be Areacircle or AreaCircle. This helps readability of your code and helps others understand your code when asking for help.

Comment: I edited some stuff, an you check LogCat again and see what the error is? Thanks